# Obtain message content of Erlang messages in dtrace

Tags: erlang, trace, dtrace

I was experimenting with Erlang and dtrace, and am interested to know whether the message content exchanged between two Erlang processes can be obtained. In particular, I am interested in the `message-send` and `message-receive` probes.

I looked at [erlang_dtrace.d](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erlang_dtrace.d) as well as [messages.d](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/runtime_tools/examples/messages.d) to see whether this is possible, but I was not able to make any progress.

Is there a way in which this can be achieved. And if not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The message-receive probe is used at line 242 here:

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4d0c23bd19f138e4fcfedd11283636e96d6bbc4f/erts/emulator/beam/msg_instrs.tab#L227

(Note that variables exposed by the probe are initialised only if the
probe itself is enabled, which is determined by the earlier macro at
227.)

Interestingly, the message itself isn't exposed, which is why you have been unable to trace it.  However, I imagine it would be feasible to patch the VM to do what you want.  You would need to render the message as a string into a buffer and expose that buffer's address;  an existing example of this idiom is

https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4d0c23bd19f138e4fcfedd11283636e96d6bbc4f/erts/emulator/beam/global.h#L1603